# Database for tenants not found

Tags: php, laravel-8, tinker

I am trying to implement Stancl/Tenancy for Laravel logic (see docs on tenancyforlaravel.com) to build a laravel application with tenants but unhappy I am unable to do so.  I tried Stancl documentation but it is not accurate

Comment: Did you follow the step from the [Installation](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/installation) document? Did you run `php artisan tenancy:install`? (Maybe you need to run `php artisan migrate` too, documentation only states "_It will create: migrations..._", not sure if it also migrates)

Comment: Yes of course, I tried everything but in vain... I tried several solutions.  but nothing works.  I followed the installation by following the steps described on the site of tenancyforlaravel.com